# Check if file from htaccess / Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-exists

In htaccess of **site.ru** I have some conditions RewriteCond, under which there is a transformation:

```
    RewriteRule ^ http://m.site.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R = 301 , L]
```

Everything works fine, except for one thing. I don't need transformation

```
    http://m.site.ru%{REQUEST_URI}
```

if this page does not exist.

How do I check

```
    http://m.site.ru%{REQUEST_URI}
```

*If it is important, m.site.ru is in /m/ folder of site.ru root.*

P.S. For several days trying to think of a solution, to no avail. Do not want to believe that i cant do it with htaccess. Or even be sure that it can not be done, then begin to develop alternatives.

UPD:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteCond /m/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond /m/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.theartstory.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cond / rule pair, the match pattern of the rule is evaluated first, then the conditions and if they all pass then the rule substitution is executed.

If the [L] flag is set on the firing rule then the remaining rules are skipped and if the [SKIP:**N**] flag is set then the following N rules are skipped.  These, plus the "-F" file existence check can implement what you want.

If you invert the logic of what you are saying then you want the redirection to occur *if* the page exists.  So why not try:

```
RewriteCond  /m/$1    -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$   http://m.site.ru/$1      [R = 301 , L]
```

You might also find that the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable is already set to `/m/` in which case you can also use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in the condition to remove the hard coded root path.

Comment: Thx, but it seems to me that this condition doesnot work... I updated the first post.

Comment: It looks to me as if your user agent conditions are both failing.  They fail for my Ubuntu laptop.  Try commenting them out to check.  See my [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the solution was to check the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/m/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/m/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
```